# Convert CSV decimal time format to time in SQL Select

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I have a csv file I'm loading into a dataset. The time field is actually a decimal value since the type is set to General. How can I convert this time (not Date) to hh:mm format in the SQL statement. I'm using c# create the dataset. I'm guessing I need to cast but can't seem to find a solution.

Time pH 0.000115741 7.4 0.0105208 7.6 0.0209375 7.9 0.0313657 7.7 0.0417824 7.6

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does the column being set to general convert a time stamp into decimal?

Comment: Good question, I do not know.

Comment: are you sure it is time stamp ?  I think it's milliseconds or something like taht.

Comment: what is the excpeted outcome? what does 0.0001157 mean? What does 7.4 mean?

Comment: 0.000157 is a time of day, no date attached.  7.4 is a measurement of pH.  It is irrelevant really I just need the first value to change to a time like for example 1:34 or 12:30.  If you past that value in an excel sheet and change the data type to time it will give you a time.  I need to be able to convert it using sql.